# Can't set a geometry data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have the datatype geometry defined. But I can't set it to one of the columns geom. as shown in the figure.

[image]

Comment: You have set a native PostgrSQL datatype "box" https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-geometric.html. You may believe that you are dealing with the datatype "geometry" that comes with the PostGIS extension, but you should clarify your question.

Comment: @user30184 I would like to set the geom to geometry datatype. how would I set it .

Comment: Please **edit the question** to specify the exact versions of PostgreSQL and PostGIS installed and confirm that you have enabled the PostGIS extension.

Comment: have you created postgis extension?

Comment: @ShahzadBacha how do I create a postgis extension ?

Comment: I created a postgis extension. and I still can not specifiy the geometry or a point

Comment: Could you send links to the tutorials which you are following?

Comment: use this query to alter geometry type 
`ALTER TABLE poi
ALTER COLUMN geom
TYPE GEOMETRY(POINT,4326)`

Comment: @ShahzadBacha I would like to add lon, lat, alt, so point is not sufficient what should I use ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to create `postgis` extension to add spatial functions such as distance, area, union, intersection, and specialty geometry data types to the database.

```
create extension postgis;
```

Then `alter` geometry column of your table, in your case `geom` column using this `SQL` query.

```
ALTER TABLE poi
ALTER COLUMN geom
TYPE GEOMETRY(POINT,4326);
```

You can set your own projection, i assume your projection is Geographic Coordinate System `(GCS WGS84)`

**Update:**

If you want to store altitude with xy, you need to use `POINTZ` instead of `POINT`.

```
 TYPE GEOMETRY(POINTZ,4326);
```

Read [this](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html)  for further information.

Comment: a point is just an xy, how would I set an altitude, x,y,z

Comment: you can store altitude in point data.. let me update my answer

Comment: when I do the above, I get the following error Column has Z dimension but geometry does not

Comment: it's because your geometry doesn't have altitude information, just latitude and longitude.